# Can't run Ubuntu core app from IDE on the device

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I have installed Ubuntu-SDK and added my Nexus 4 with flashed Ubuntu as a device. The device is shown as online and I can run a "Hello world" app created by clicking "File" -> "New file or project". But I can't run a core application Dropping letters by opening it in the IDE and clicking the Run button. I get the following message:

```
Sdk-Launcher> Error: This application is already installed on the device, 
uninstall it or temporarily change the name in the manifest.json file!
```

Of course I removed the pre-installed Dropping letters by long tap on the icon and Uninstall. I also tried to run the app in an Ubuntu Emulator, where I get the same error message although there's no Dropping Letters preinstalled on Emulator at all. Anybody knows how to make this work?

Note: I also tried to change Name in `manifest.json`. After that, the application starts, but the main QML file isn't loaded.

Answer (score 1):

After some chat with Ubuntu touch team I'm posting the fix. It turns out that Ubuntu SDK is outdated on Ubuntu 14.04, it must be updated like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/tools-development
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then, edit /usr/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/scripts/qtc_device_applaunch.py as a super user and remove the following lines:

```
    else:
        print("Sdk-Launcher> Uninstalling already installed package (--force-install)")
        success = subprocess.call(["pkcon","remove",package_name+";"+package_version+";"+package_arch+";local:click","-p"],stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
        if success != 0:
            print("Sdk-Launcher> Uninstalling the application failed",flush=True)
            sys.exit(1)
```

After that I needed to alter the 'Exec' line in dropping-letters.desktop to this:

```
Exec=qmlscene dropping-letters.qml
```

Piece of cake, isn't it? :-P